# Taylor expansion in python

Tags: python, series, taylor-series

How do I calculate and print out the value of ln(1+x) using the series expansion:

ln(1+x) expansion

[image]

using a while loop and including terms whose magnitude is greater than 10-8. Print out the sum to each number of terms to show the result converging.

So far this is my code but it calculates lnsum2 to be a very large number and hence never ends.

```
n=1 
lnsum2= np.cumsum((((-1)**(n+1)*(x**n)/n))) 
while lnsum2>10**-8: 
       n+=1 
       lnsum2 = lnsum2 + np.cumsum((((-1)**(n+1)*(x**n)/n))) 
else: print('The sum of terms greater than 10^-8 is:', lnsum2)
```

Many thanks.

Right I've now got code that works using a while loop. Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: please post your code in the question, not comments.

Comment: What is `xn`? What do you expect `n+1` to do? Do you mean `n += 1`? Your while statement checks `lnsum2` which I take it is the **entire** result, and not the individual term. Also please fix the indentation

Comment: Hi hopefully that fixes your issues

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's a bit over-kill, but here's a nice solution using [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) to evaluate infinite series.

```
from sympy.abc import k
from sympy import Sum, oo as inf
import math

x = 0.5

result = Sum(
    (
        x**(2*k-1) /
         (2*k-1)
    ) - (
        x**(2*k) / (2*k)
    ),

    (k, 1, inf)).doit()

#print(result) # 0.5*hyper((0.5, 1), (3/2,), 0.25) - 0.14384103622589
print(float(result)) # 0.4054651081081644

print(math.log(x+1, math.e)) # 0.4054651081081644
```

**EDIT:**

I think the problem with your original code is that you haven't quite implemented the series (if I'm understanding the figure in your question correctly). It looks like the series you're trying to implement can be represented as

```
      x^(2n-1)       x^(2n)
( +  ----------  -  -------- ... for n = 1 to n = infinity )
        2n-1           2n
```

whereas your code actually implements this series

```
 (-1)^2 * (x * 1)    (  (-1)^(n+1) * (x^n)                                  )
----------------- + (  --------------------  ... for n = 2 to n = infinity   ) 
        1            (          n                                           )
```

**EDIT 2:**

If you really have to do the iterations yourself, rather than using sympy, here is code which works:

```
import math

x = 0.5

n=0
sums = []

while True:
    n += 1
    this_sum = (x**(2*n-1) / (2*n-1)) - (x**(2*n) / (2*n))
    if abs(this_sum) < 1e-8:
        break

    sums.append(this_sum)

lnsum = sum(sums)

print('The sum of terms greater than 10^-8 is:\t\t', lnsum)
print('math.log yields:\t\t\t\t', math.log(x+1, math.e))
```

Output:

```
The sum of terms greater than 10^-8 is:      0.4054651046035002
math.log yields:                             0.4054651081081644
```

Comment: what did you want to change in the while loop? if you want to change x, simply encase the whole thing (except import statements) with a loop. `sympy` approximates the value of the series for you, so you don't have to worry about iterating to make the result more accurate...

Comment: Well I don't know how to use sympy so I would prefer to do this using a while loop and numpy. cheers